# Number of Events in last 3 months

Tags: event, roll-up-summary

I log events against my accounts, and would like to display a field on which I count the number of closed events in the last 6 months. I tried doing that using a roll up field, but that won't work, as it's not a MD relationship. 
Is there a way to do this without code?

Tks, Lily

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [Roll-up Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) which is free from the App Exchange. It will allow you to roll up just about any information with clicks instead of code and not just on M-D relationships.